# Segue animations break

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, animation

A lot of times the segue animations in my app do break. When this happens all these animation flick at once instead of the popover/slide transitions. I don't use any custom segue animations. I can't find what a reason for this behaviour  could be so I don't know where to start with debugging. I tried symbolic breakpoints but so far no luck. What can be the reason that the animations break?

My storyboard is:

Tab Bar View controller > Navigation controller > Table view controller > push to other storyboard > navigation controller > Table view controller

Comment: What is your question and what have you tried so far? Please read [http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The animations did break because an UIImageView was updated outside the main thread.

Fixed it by wrapping it in:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
    //update image view
})
```